# Website opened selenium just stop working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, opera

Website opened in selenium just stops working after a few seconds but rest of the code works without problem , I tried opening the site in opera as well in chrome but with the same result when I tried to open shorter version of this program in basic Ide it worked without a problem but when I tried to run this version in pycharm it again didnt worked

Code:

from selenium import webdriver

def web(): driver = webdriver.Opera() driver.get('website') web()

Comment: Please provide code that I can test with

Comment: It's not clear what "rest of the code works without problem" means in this context. Try rewriting with a numbered list of steps that you follow when seeing this problem. Then say specifically what you expected to happen. Then say specifically what happened instead.

Comment: Could you show the source code of your Selenium test? And some logs or output when you ran it?

Comment: Soulution is that it cant be used as def